# Kubernetes maintaining dead minion list

Tags: kubernetes

When i do `kubectl get nodes` it gives me

```
Name         Status
192.168.1.10 NotReady
192.168.1.11 Ready
192.168.1.12 Ready
```

Here node **192.168.1.10** as been completed deleted, but still this is listed in nodes list.

Because of this when im trying to run kubernetes ui, it is looking for

```
GET http://<Master-Node>/api/v1/proxy/nodes/192.168.1.10:4194/api/v1.0/machine
```

And this is giving **503 (Service unavailable)** error

Looks like some sort of cached data, How do i delete this dead minion from the list?

Answer (score 2):

On some cloud providers, nodes will be automatically removed from the node list when the VM is deleted (because the master components can verify with an authoritative API that the VM is in fact not coming back). On bare metal (or cloud providers where that extra hook has not been implemented), the node will exist in a `NotReady` state indefinitely until a cluster administrator manually removes it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious what you mean when you say the node has been completely deleted. Did you delete a cloud VM? Take a bare metal server off the network?

In any case, if you want to get rid of it, running `kubectl delete node 192.168.1.10` on it should remove it from the API.